# Call paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am trying to paint a line when my variable `readyToDraw` is `TRUE` by using an `if...` statement in class's  `Paint` method `paintComponent()` . I guess I'm doing something wrong because the line never gets painted. How do I fix this? Is there a way to call `paintComponent()` from another method? 
Full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;

public class MainFrame {
    public int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    private boolean readyToDraw = false;
    private int clickCount = 0;
    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        buttonPanel.setBounds(10, 11, 100, 85);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel paint = new Paint();
        frame.getContentPane().add(paint);

        JButton btnLine = new JButton("Line");
        btnLine.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnLine.setBounds(4, 4, 92, 25);

        btnLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                if (readyToDraw == true) {
                    System.out.println("Let's draw!");
                }

                else {

                }
                System.out.println("Line");

            }
        });

        JButton btnRectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
        btnRectangle.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnRectangle.setBounds(4, 30, 92, 25);

        btnRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                if (readyToDraw == true) {
                    System.out.println("Let's draw!");
                }

                else {

                }
                System.out.println("Rectangle");
            }
        });

        JButton btnCircle = new JButton("Circle");
        btnCircle.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnCircle.setBounds(4, 56, 92, 25);

        btnCircle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                if (readyToDraw == true) {
                    System.out.println("Let's draw!");
                }

                else {

                }
                System.out.println("Circle");
            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(btnLine);
        buttonPanel.add(btnRectangle);
        buttonPanel.add(btnCircle);
    }

    private class Paint extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        public Paint() {
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setBounds(120, 11, 664, 550);
            this.addMouseListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //if (readyToDraw) {

                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            //}
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            Image image = toolkit.getImage("cursor.png");
            Point hotSpot = new Point(15, 15);
            Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Dot");
            this.setCursor(cursor);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            Cursor dotCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
            this.setCursor(dotCursor);

        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int x1 = 0;
            int y1 = 0;
            int x2 = 0;
            int y2 = 0;
            if (clickCount == 0) {
                x1 = e.getX();
                y1 = e.getY();
                clickCount++;

            } else if (clickCount == 1) {
                x2 = e.getX();
                y2 = e.getY();
                clickCount++;
                readyToDraw = true;
            } else {
                clickCount = 0;
                readyToDraw = false;
                repaint();
            }

            System.out.println(x1 + " " + y1 + " " + clickCount + " " + x2
                    + " " + y2 + readyToDraw);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem in a bad way (to my opinion), so helping you to do this is not a good idea. Instead, I would like to know what is your high-level goal, so that we can think about a better implementation

Comment: Painting is a destructive process, in order to maintain what was previously painted you either need to maintain some kind of model which can describe the actions needed to be carried out each time `paintComponent` is called, or render your output to a `BufferedImage` which can simply be painted when ever `paintComponent` is called.

Comment: The final goal of the whole application looks something like this: user clicks twice on the `Paint` panel, while the clicks are being executed, the application takes click coordinates and after the second click the variable `readyToDraw` is set to `TRUE` and a shape is drawn (my code should include a few other shapes in near future).

Comment: @MadProgrammer, is there a way to fulfill my idea without using any arrays or buffered images? Buffered image is not a very good way to save your work anyways, and if I choose arrays, it will take me a year to finish this application.

Comment: Short answer, no...*"Buffered image is not a very good way to save your work anyways"* - I'd disagree, `ImageIO.write(img, "png", file)` is much easier and you'd need to "paint" the contents of the panel to a `BufferedImage` first anyway...And I'd use a `List` of some kind personally

Comment: So I should use a `List` or an `Array` , somehow pass the variables to `paintComponent` and then what? Use `repaint()` ?

Comment: Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It contains working examples for both the List and BufferedImage approaches.